# meaning of J phrase: 10&+~20

Tags: j

I was trying to do `20 + 10` in such a way as:

```
(10&+~) 20
```

Then I realize that adverb `&` has "short right-hand". So it should be

```
(10&(+~)) 20
```

which gives me the correct answer: 30. But just out of curiosity

```
(10&+~) 20
```

gives 220. Why?

More strangely,

```
(10&+~) 0.1
```

gives "domain error'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(10&+~) 20`  is `10 (&+~) 20`. This seems like a fork or a hook but it isn't because `~` and `&` are special snowflakes. `~` has to be dealt with first, so your expression is `10 (&+)~ 20`. Now, `&+` can not stand on its own, so `~` has to be reflexive here. Your expression now is

```
20 (10 (&+)) 20
```

which now leads to the special dyadic case of bond-`&` that becomes a power (`^:`):  `x m&v y ↔ m&v^:x y`. So, finally, the expression becomes:

```
(10&+)^:20 ] 20
220
```

Obviously, you can't use power with non-integers, so `(10&+~)0.1` is a domain error.

Comment: You are right. This is documented in J's official "Vocabulary". I was looking up the "NuVoc". It's not mentioned in there.